# C++ string concatenation in compile time

Tags: c++

I want to write logger and I need data about source file and line.
Does this line of code work in compile time or not:

```
constexpr std::string_view source = (std::string(__FILE__) + ":" + std::to_string(__LINE__));
```

If it doesn't work in compile time, how will I do it? Maybe is it impossible?

Comment: That doesn't compile at all

Comment: You have a dangling reference. `source` is a non-owning view of a temporary object that is destroyed at the end of the full expression. You should make `source` a simple owning `std::string` instead

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would work without allocating, and also compile time

```
#include <iostream>

#define STR_(X) #X
#define STR(X) STR_(X)

int main() 
{
    //constexpr std::string_view(const char*) doesn't work in some versions of gcc, but is a better alternative if the compiler supports it
    constexpr const char* str = __FILE__ ":" STR(__LINE__);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, concatenation is done in pre compile time, and not in compile time :-)

Answer (score 3):

If I get it right, `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` are Makros. Do this:

```
#define STRING(s) #s
constexpr std::string_view source = STRING(__FILE__) + ":" + STRING(__LINE__);
```

It should definetely work in compile time.

---

### Update:

As mentioned in the comments, my approach will not work. Because `STRING(__LINE__)` will convert to `"__LINE__"`. So I need to do this:

```
#define _STRING(s) #s
#define STRING(s) _STRING(s)
constexpr std::string_view source = __FILE__ ":" STRING(__LINE__);
```

By the way, `__FILE__` gives already back a char[], so I dont need to convert it and funfact: the compiler concatenates automatically adjacent strings, so I dont need the `+` either.

Thank you for pointing out the errors in my code.
I leave the bug here, so others can learn from my mistakes too.

Comment: main.cpp:8:59: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const char [9]' and 'const char [2]')

Comment: Even if you remove the `+` it will still only store  `"__FILE__:__LINE__"`

Comment: That `STRING` macro needs another level of indirection. See the answer by @Mestkon.